# Saying "HaMakom yenachem..." multiple times

Tags: number, blessing, mourning-aveilus

Does one say "HaMakom yenachem..." each time one visits/leaves a shiva house or only once during the shiva period? I recall someone telling me one only says it once, but I cannot find any source for this.

Answer (score 1):

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef ([*Hichot Avelut* 26:10](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_66.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%9B%D7%95B-B%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92B%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%99)) writes:

(*translation mine*)

> יש שמקפידים שלא ילך אדם לנחם אבלים פעמיים, אלא פעם אחת בלבד. אולם אין מנהגינו להקפיד בזה, ואדרבה בכל פעם שהולך לנחם מקיים מצות ניחום אבלים. ובפרט אם הולך להתפלל שם כמה פעמים. [ילקו''י אבלות מהדורת תשס''ד סימן כו סעיף י עמוד תלה]
>
> There are those who are careful to not visit mourners twice; [they should] only [visit] one time. However, our custom is not to worry about it, and on the contrary, each time one goes to comfort [a mourner] he fulfills the *mitzvah* of comforting mourners. This applies especially if he goes there to *daven* many times.